# Rails 3 mail to users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want send newsletter to all registered users, but only the last user (in database) receive the mail.

```
 def letter(nletter)
   @nletter = nletter
   @users=Newsletter.all
   @users.each do |users|
    mail(:to => users.email, :subject => @nletter.subject)
   end
  end
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code you showed us is in your Mailer class, it's because the `mail` method just sets various attributes on a Mail object.  When you loop through all your users and call `mail` for each one, you're just resetting the subject and (more importantly) the recipient on a *single* Mail object.  So when the function finishes and the Mail is sent out, the current recipient is the last user you set it to - the last user in your database.

You can get around this in two different ways.  If it's a generic e-mail (everybody gets the same exact message), you can just pass an array of e-mail addresses as `:to`:

**Note:**  As Josh points out in the comments, you'll pretty much always want to use `:bcc` instead of `:to`, so you don't end up broadcasting your entire mailing list.

```
def letter(nletter)
    @nletter = nletter
    @users=Newsletter.all
    mail(:to => @users.map(&:email), :subject => @nletter.subject)
end
```

But if each user gets a custom e-mail (`"Hi, #{username}!"` or somesuch), you'll have to create a new Mail object for each user.  You can do this by calling `Mailer.deliver_letter(nletter, user)` for each user:

```
# Somewhere outside of your Mailer:
nletter = "...whatever..."
Newsletter.all.each do |user|
    Mailer.deliver_letter(nletter, user)
end

# And your mailer function would look like:
def letter(nletter, user)
    @nletter = nletter
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => @nletter.subject)
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just a side note, if you're sending out a generic email, you should put the array of users' email addresses in the BCC field so the email addresses don't get shared with each other.